# Shopping Basket list method needs a return type c#

Tags: c#, methods, return

Hello I am trying to make a shopping basket program for some coursework I have been given a diffent type of "Shopping basket" to follow but i cant get my list to keep updating. so the problem im having is the 'ShoppingBasketList()' needs a return type but in the example i got given it does not. i have spent ages trying to work out why and i just cant. if anyone has any idea would be a great help!

```
public class ShoppingBasket
{
    public List<ShoppingBasketItem> Items { get; private set; }        


     public ShoppingBasketList()
    {
      Items = new List<ShoppingBasketItem>();
    }

    internal static void AddToList(string productName, int quantity, decimal latestPrice)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            // if the item is already in the list
            if (Items[i].ItemName == productName)
            {
                Items[i].UpdateShoppingBasketList(quantity, latestPrice);
                return;
            }
        }

        // It's not in the list
        ShoppingBasketItem sbi = new ShoppingBasketItem(productName, quantity, latestPrice);
        Items.Add(sbi);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public ShoppingBasketList() { ... }` is a constructor declaration. Change the name to `ShoppingBasket` or change the name of your class to `ShoppingBasketList`.

Comment: `public class ShoppingBasket` needs the constructor `public ShoppingBasket`. `ShoppingBasketList` is not a valid constructors name here and in this context, it will be seen as a method that either needs void or a type as return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ShoppingBasketList()
{
    Items = new List<ShoppingBasketItem>();
}
```

Is a constructor declaration (because it does not specify a return type). A constructor should always have the same name as the class it belongs to. Your constructor is called `ShoppingBasketList` while your class is called `ShoppingBasket`. You should rename your class to `ShoppingBasketList` *or* rename your constructor to `ShoppingBasket`.

eg.

```
public ShoppingBasket()
{
    Items = new List<ShoppingBasketItem>();
}
```

You can read a bit more about constructors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx).

Comment: Yes, somebody has tweaked the example before they gave it to you and renamed the class and forgotten to rename the constructor too.

Comment: Thank you! cant believe i spent so long for one word :P

Answer (score 0):

Your program is notifying you of a return type because you have specified a `return;`. Therefore remove the `return` in your `for`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
{
    // if the item is already in the list
    if (Items[i].ItemName == productName)
    {
        Items[i].UpdateShoppingBasketList(quantity, latestPrice);
        return; //replace me with something else...
    }
}
```

Instead, add a [looping invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) `notFound` (or `break`).

```
Boolean notFound = true;
for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count && notFound; i++)
{
    // if the item is already in the list
    if (Items[i].ItemName == productName)
    {
        Items[i].UpdateShoppingBasketList(quantity, latestPrice);
        notFound = false; //exiting the the loop
    }
}
```

Oh and your method `ShoppingBasketList` is written as a constructor (anything that is `public <Insert Name Here>` is a constructor) which is called upon when declaring the class for example `ShoppingBasket sb = new ShoppingBasket();`.

```
 public ShoppingBasketList()
{
  Items = new List<ShoppingBasketItem>();
}
```

Either rename it as your class name, `public ShoppingBasket` or remove it altogether and initialize your `Items` in the `declaration`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to those above who correctly state that you should rename ShoppingBasketList() to ShoppingBasket(), you don't need a method with a return value to get to see your items.  You already have declared Items to be a List.  From you ShoppingBasket() object, you will get your list by myShoppingBasket.Items